# Configure NTP server on RedHat to allow every incoming client

Tags: redhat, ntp

Is it possible to configure NTP server to allow any incoming IP to sync from, witout specifying ranges and networks?

Comment: The default config does that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 restrict default limited notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
```

Or:

```
 restrict default kod limited notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
```

The latter config statement enables the use of KOD packets and the former simply does not respond to clients that exceed the default limits.  I do not think sending KODs to misbehaving clients makes any sense so I use the former.